# Style select::-ms-expand when disabled

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-selectors

How do I change the background colour of `select::-ms-expand` when it's disabled?

```
select::-ms-expand{
    background: #f60;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add `:disabled` before `::-ms-expand`, like so:

```css
select:disabled::-ms-expand {
    background: #f60;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Enabled</option>
</select>
<select disabled>
  <option>Disabled</option>
</select>
```

Comment: looks good. why does the changes show only in IE? How can I make it work in all browsers?

Comment: @Becky: As the `-ms-` prefix suggests, `::-ms-expand` is specific to IE only. Unfortunately there is no equivalent in other browsers. You would likely have to use a custom dropdown control if you want full control over how to style these elements.

Comment: @user4749485: Selectors doesn't currently allow pseudo-elements to have dynamic pseudo-classes. That *is* odd, which is why [the upcoming standard will relax this restriction](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4/#pseudo-elements).