# Select button style in moziila firefox

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, css-selectors

I did the select element style change in IE as follows:

```
select::-ms-expand {
    width: 12px;
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
}
```

Which looks as follows in Internet Explorer,

[image]

When I try the same style in Mozilla Firefox, it looks as follows,

[image: Mozilla Firefox select option]

Same style I need to do in Mozilla Firefox , but I don't know how to do it. Any ideas on how to implement the same style so it is compatible with Mozilla Firefox?

Comment: Replacing `-ms-` with `-moz-`?

Comment: -moz-expand is not define at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference/Mozilla_Extensions. Though I have tested it is not working. :(

Comment: I have already tried all the options as described in there it is not giving output as expected

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Style select::-ms-expand when disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30482736/style-select-ms-expand-when-disabled)

Answer (score 0):

As I mention in the comment on my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30482736/style-select-ms-expand-when-disabled#comment49044290_30482820), there is no equivalent to `::-ms-expand` in other browsers. If you would like to roll your own custom select control, you will need to use some sort of UI library to do this rather than a conventional `<select>` element.

Comment: You are right I had tried bootstrap-select ui library to do this but I don't want extra code and need a simple way to do it as I did for IE